# IntelliJ IDEA says Maven class not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA. I have one sample Java code which requires MySQL driver class using `class.forName();` to get database connection. It is a standalone Java application. When I run the main method of that class, I get `ClassNotFoundException`. But, I have that sample code in a Maven project in which MySQL jar is configured. What am I missing? Eclipse does the job.

Comment: check in .m2 folder if mysql.jar is present or not

Comment: @SpringLearner Actually the scope was the problem. I just provided it as an answer so that others may find it useful. But, the same pom.xml and project when used with the eclipse ide there is no problem.

Comment: It will be useful for the new comers to know why someone is downvoting. Otherwise the person may actually keep committing the same mistake. The question was asked as the other ide did its job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your kind answers. I found that the maven dependency is scoped to 'provided'. So, `Intellij IDEA` was not looking out for that jar because of the scope. When I changed the scope to `compile(no scope tag)`, it is working fine. But without any change the configuration worked fine in `Eclipse`.

Comment: It means default value ( also is `compile` scope): http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: @dovy Yes. Default scope is compile. Only then Intellij is including it in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to Manven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

And checklist: 
- `%M2_HOME%`
- `.m2` directory existing.
- Check internet connection.
- Check enabling Maven plugin inside IntelliJ IDEA.
- Add [MySQL ConnectorJ](http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar) jar file to `lib` inside application server.

Answer (score 0):

There are different scope for maven import

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

Check. Scope should not be `provided.`